# Cosine similarity output using Numpy & Sklearn differ

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, numpy-ndarray, cosine-similarity

I've the following code. I am trying to find why the cosine similarity differs when using numpy dot product versus sklearn cosine similarity. I think this is related to the arrays being more than 1-D, but am not sure why this might be the case. Any explanation would be helpful

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

a=np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
b=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,4,6],[4,4,6]])

dot = np.dot(a, b)
norma = np.linalg.norm(a)
normb = np.linalg.norm(b)
cos = dot / (norma * normb)

#[[0.32403703 0.33946737 0.50920105]
# [0.32403703 0.33946737 0.50920105]]

cosine_similarity(a, b)
#[[0.96000145 0.9258201  0.94976937]
# [0.96000145 0.9258201  0.94976937]]
```

Comment: Looking at the source code for the `cosine_similarity` method shows that it uses [`sklearn.preprocessing.normalize`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html) which by default only does normalization on `axis=1` instead of on the whole array as is the case for `numpy.linalg.norm`

Comment: Thanks. I tried using np.dot(a, b)/ (np.linalg.norm(a, axis=1)*np.linalg.norm(b, axis=1)) but this gives an error

```---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-4c148bb44c6f> in <module>
----> 1 np.dot(a, b)/ (np.linalg.norm(a, axis=1)*np.linalg.norm(b, axis=1))

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (3,) ```

Comment: Yes I tried that as well but had to reshape the norms to `(2, 1)` and `(3, 1)` but still didn't get the right answer. I would just follow through the source code from [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html). You can click the `[source]` button in the top right